# How can edit Minipage so it doesn't overload right margin?

Tags: minipage

I'm trying to make a cover using minipage for the logos on the top of the page, but it overloads the right margin

Here's the code:

```
\documentclass[hidelinks,a4paper,11pt,draft]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{draftfigure}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
    \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
        $\vcenter{\hbox{\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{tyty.png}}}$
        \hfill
        $\vcenter{\hbox{\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{kile.png}}}$
    \end{minipage}%
\end{titlepage}

\end{document}
```

And here's a screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Commenting out the `\minipage` environment does it for me. It is not needed here. your first image (tyty) is indented, use `\noindent`. Edit: Got ninja'ed, @David's answer provides a better and fuller explanation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's indented by the paragarph indentation so

```
    \noindent
    \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
```

but the minipage is doing nothing here, and `\vcenter` and `\hbox` are not really latex constructs either,

```
\documentclass[hidelinks,a4paper,11pt,draft]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{draftfigure}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
    \noindent
    \includegraphics[valign=c,width=0.2\textwidth]{tyty.png}%
        \hfill
    \includegraphics[valign=c,width=0.3\textwidth]{kile.png}%
\end{titlepage}

\end{document}
```